# Kontsevich integral on tangles and Fubini

Tags: knot-theory, quantum-groups

I am reading about the Kontsevich integral, following this  text : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/635b/c6370e8aba381724eaaa36abefba7f7a5bec.pdf

At some point (page 10 to be exact) the author claims that if you have two composable tangles $T_1$ and $T_2$ then we have $$
Z(T_1 \bullet T_2) = Z(T_1) Z(T_2)$$
where for a tangle $T$, $Z(T)$ denotes its Kontsevich integral.

This may be a somewhat stupid question but for some reason I can not see the reason why.

Comment: This is not entirely obvious especially since in this survey they're not completely precise in defining the Kontsevich integral for tangles. You can find a proof here: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~lescop/preprints/intkon.pdf